# How to prove perpendicular vectors problem

Tags: vector-spaces, orthonormal

If I have:
$$|\underline a + \underline b| = |\underline a - \underline b|$$ how do I prove that $\underline a$ is perpendicular to $\underline b$?

Answer (score 2):

First we say norm of vector and not absolute value of vector. Second we have
$$\langle a,b\rangle=\frac14(||a+b||^2-||a-b||^2)$$
which gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as given elsewhere really, but possibly in a more familiar notation:
$$\|a+b\|^2=(a+b)\cdot(a+b)=a\cdot a+2a\cdot b+b\cdot b$$
and
$$\ \|a-b\|^2=(a-b)\cdot(a-b)=a\cdot a-2a\cdot b+b\cdot b\ ;$$
since these are equal we have $2a\cdot b=-2a\cdot b$, so $a\cdot b=0$, so the vectors are perpendicular.